# Smooth color change problems

Tags: python-3.x, colors, smoothing

Here's some code that should make the color change smoothly from one to another:

```
def make_color(k, color1='#ff0000', color2='#00ff00'):
    diff = int(color2[1:], base=16)-int(color1[1:], base=16)
    color = hex(int(color1[1:], base=16)+int(diff*k))[2:]
    l = 6-len(color)
    return '#'+l*'0'+color
```

When I run it, it doesn't change color smoothly. Color is correct only for some values of `k` (including 1 and 0). Otherwise, the wrong color is returned.
How to fix that?

Comment: you need to work on separate rgb values, not whole number